# LINQ Include slowing down performance when searching

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

We have the following method that allows us to search a table of Projects for a DataGrid:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetFilteredProjects(string searchString)
{
    var projects = _context.Projects.Where(p => p.Current);

    projects.Include(p => p.Client);
    projects.Include(p => p.Architect);
    projects.Include(p => p.ProjectManager);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        projects = projects
            .Where(p => p.NormalizedFullProjectName.Contains(searchString)
                    || p.Client.NormalizedName.Contains(searchString)
                    || p.Architect.NormalizedFullName.Contains(searchString)
                    || p.ProjectManager.NormalizedFullName.Contains(searchString));
    }

    projects = projects.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Take(10);

    return await projects.ToListAsync();
}
```

If we do not use the `Include` on the projects then the searching is instantaneous. However, after adding them in the search can take over 3 seconds.

We need to include the other Entities to allow the Users to search on them should they want to.

How are we able to improve performance but still keep the `Include` to allow searching on them?

Without `Incldue` the method looks like so:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Project>> GetFilteredProjects(string searchString)
{
    var projects = _context.Projects.Where(p => p.Current);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        projects = projects
            .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchString));
    }

    projects = projects.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Take(10);

    return await projects.ToListAsync();
}
```

Without `Include` the performance looks like so:

[image]

With `Include`:

[image]

Comment: Look at Task Manager and check you memory usage.  I suspect having the Include is add to you memory and swapping is occurring slowing down the run-time.

Comment: Have you run a trace on your SQL database? It may be that you are missing an index or something.

Comment: "We need to include the other Entities to allow the Users to search on them should they want to" - that's not true I think. Search (`Where` clause) is not related to includes.

Comment: The NormalizedFullName field, is this something stored as a field in the database as well? I am just guessing here but that field may not be indexed. When I am dealing with people name searches I would be using a surname and then potentially the first name.

Comment: A side note - in your example `Include`s have no effect since you are not assigning back the returned object to the `projects` variable.

Comment: If that's your real code, then the differences in performance are coming from additional joins / checks introduced by the navigation property access in the `Where` predicate, which depending on the database table indexes may generate suboptimal SQL query plan.

Comment: @Andrew: The performance hit of an absent index would not disappear if just the `Include` statements were commented out.

Comment: @Evk: Consider the difference between in-memory and in-database filtering.

Comment: @Flater I still think my sentence holds. If in-memory filtering happens - that's a bug OP should fix. Only valid way to go here is database filtering and for that Includes are not needed (and as Ivan mentions above - they do not even have any effect in OP code, since he does not assign result to variable).

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is that including all the extra entities takes time and effort, thus increasing the load times.

However, there is a flaw in your assumption:

> We need to include the other Entities to allow the Users to search on them should they want to.

That is not (necessarily) correct. Filtering happens on the database level. `Include` tells Entity Framework to load the records **from** the database. These are two separate things.

Look at the following examples:

```
_context.Projects
        .Include(p => p.Architect)
        .Where(p => p.Architect.Name == "Bob")
        .ToList()
```

This will give you a list of projects (and their architects) who have an architect named Bob.

```
_context.Projects
        .Where(p => p.Architect.Name == "Bob")
        .ToList()
```

This will give you a list of projects (without architects) who have an architect named Bob; but it does not actually load the `Architect` object into memory.

```
_context.Projects
        .Include(p => p.Architect)
        .ToList()
```

This will give you a list of projects (and their architects). It will contain *every* project, the list is not filtered.

---

You only need to use `Include` when you want to do **in-memory** filtering, i.e. on a collection that was already loaded from the database.

Whether that is the case for you depends on this part:

```
    projects = projects
        .Where(p => p.NormalizedFullProjectName.Contains(searchString)
                || p.Client.NormalizedName.Contains(searchString)
                || p.Architect.NormalizedFullName.Contains(searchString)
                || p.ProjectManager.NormalizedFullName.Contains(searchString));
```

If `NormalizedFullProjectName` (and the other properties) are database columns, then EF is able to perform the filtering at the database level. You do not need the `Include` for filtering the items.

If `NormalizedFullProjectName` (and the other properties) are not database columns, then EF will first have to load the items in memory before it can apply the filter. In this case, you do need the `Include`, because the architects (and others) need to be loaded in memory.

---

If you are only loading the related entities for filtering purposes (not display purposes), and you are doing the filtering on the database level; then you can simply remove the include statements.

If you need those related entities to be loaded (for in-memory filtering, or for display purposes), then you can't easily remove the `Include` statements, unless you write a `Select` that specifies the fields you need.

For example:

```
_context.Projects
        .Select(p => new { Project = p, ArchitectName = p.Architect.Name })
        .ToList()
```

This will load the project entities (in their entirety) but only the name of the architect and none of the other properties. This can be a significant performance boost if your related entities have many properties that you currently do not need.

*Note: The current example uses an anonymous type. I generally advocate creating a custom type for this; but that's unrelated to the performance issue we're addressing here.*

---

**Update**

Based on your update, you seemingly imply that the intended filtering happens after the objects have been loaded from the database.

This is the source of your performance problems. You are fetching a lot of data but only show part of it. The data that does not get shown still needs to be loaded, which is wasted effort.

There are separate arguments for performance here:

- **Load everything once** - Load all the data once (which might take a long time), but then allow the user to filter the loaded data (which is very fast)
- **Load chunks** - Only load the data that matches the applied filters. If the user changes the filters, you load the data again. The first load will be much faster, but the subsequent filtering actions will take longer compared to in-memory filtering.

What you should do here is not my decision. It's a matter of priorities. Some customers prefer one over the other. I would say that in most cases, the second option (loading chunks) is the better option here, as it prevents needlessly loading a massive dataset if the user never looks through 90% of it. That's a waste of performance and network load.

The answer I gave applies to the "load chunks" approach.

If you decide to take the "load everything once" approach, then you will have to accept the performance hit of that initial load. The best you can do is severely limit the returned data columns (like I showed with the `Select`) in order to minimize the performance/network cost.

I see no reasonable argument to mix these two approaches. You'll end up with both drawbacks.

Comment: Wow. What an answer. First of all thanks. Where you say that we are loading all of the data before filtering, we believed that this line: `projects = projects.OrderBy(p => p.Name).Take(10);` would mean that when the command is executed on the Database we only take the first 10, therefore not loading the entire set. Is this the correct assumption to make?

Comment: @CBreeze: [Queryable.Take returns a Queryable object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906(v=vs.110).aspx), so it seems to me that it does not load the data yet. As far as I'm aware, the data is loaded by calling method which either enumerate the list, or return a non-enumerable value (single, first, sum, count, max, ...)

Comment: @CBreeze: Also, I think `Take` is a non-issue here. The `Take` happens _after_ the filtering on related entities; so even if `Take` did enumerate the collection, you would still be able to first do an in-database filtering.

Comment: @CBreeze note that you are using EF Core. Unlike EF6, if Core for whatever reason cannot translate your query to SQL - it will pull all data to memory and perform operation there (unless you explicitly tell it to throw exception in this case). That might or might not happen in your case, but worth keeping in mind.